# making the output file from db2 displays the process of table creations from shell scipt?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, shell, db2

I created a shell script such that will create a string that contain the process of table creation for db2 . As in Example:
string=" db2 "CREATE TABLE foo (......... ""

Now my script will connect to the database and input the string which translate to db2 that will create a table .Before shell inputs the string , I enabled on db2 the command

db2 update command options using z on test-database.txt
so that I want to save  all the outputs on textfile
 However, my problem is I want to for that string to show in the output file created by db2 just like when you are typing in db2 to create a table, but in never shows in the output file. It rather  will show the result whether table successfully created or not  in test-database.txt , e.g

The SQL command completed successfully.

Is there a way to make the output file show the creation of table ? . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about the options for the db2clp, which has many different options.

If I understood, you are writing a script (a bash script, I think so) and you want to retrieve the command output. For this, you have two options

- Write the command output into a file, and then read the file.
- Redirect the command output to a varaible.

The first option is the easier one. This option uses the z option, that writes the whole output to a file. You can change this behaviour just by printing out what you want, and then redirecting the output to a file.

```
db2 -tf myfile.sql -z /tmp/output
VAR=$(cat /tmp/output)
```

The second option is a little tricky, because redirection implies the creation of another shell, and then you should reload the db2 profile. This option uses the v option, that is the standard output, and I hope the output is what you want to have.

```
VAR=$(. ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile ; db2 -tvf myfile.sql)
```

Finally, you just need to process the content of VAR, via awk, sed, grep, etc.

For more information: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010410.html